# Scraping data from KendoUI interface using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from [this website](https://laerm-monitoring.de/mittelung?mp=14) using selenium and python (note the website is in German but can be translated using Chrome's translate function). Specifically, I would like to automate the process of (1) selecting "24 hours" from the  "averaging" dropdown, (2) selecting "maximum" from the "Period" dropdown, and finally (3) clicking the "export" button and downloading the associated Excel file.

I have limited scraping experience, but when I have done it in the past, I have found and clicked on items using their xpath (i.e., using `driver.find_element('xpath', ...).click()`). However, although I'm able to find what seem to be the correct xpaths here, when I try to interact with them, Selenium returns an `ElementNotInteractableException`. I would really appreciate any guidance on how to scrape this site. I am open to solution that do not use Selenium.

Comment: try to use javascript in your python code like this : 
`driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('nameofyourclass')[0].click()")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Json data directly without `selenium`, for example into a Pandas dataframe and then save it as `csv`/`xls`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.laerm-monitoring.de/mittelung?mp=14'
api_url = 'https://www.laerm-monitoring.de/Mittelung/Chartdata_Read'


headers = {'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'}

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    token = soup.select_one('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]')['value']

    payload = {
        "sort": "",
        "group": "",
        "filter": "",
        "__RequestVerificationToken": token,
        "avgtype": "0",
        "mpnumber": "14",
        "daytime": "2",
        "numMonths": "0",
        "endDate": "0"
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(s.post(api_url, data=payload, headers=headers).json())
    print(df.head(20))
    df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)  # save it as CSV
```

Prints:

```
                   Date    Lr  CountnoGZ  CountGZ
0   2019-09-20T00:00:00  66.6         16       19
1   2019-09-21T00:00:00  67.8        133       26
2   2019-09-22T00:00:00  69.1        154       25
3   2019-09-23T00:00:00  70.6        163       56
4   2019-09-24T00:00:00  72.3        160       71
5   2019-09-25T00:00:00  71.0        163       67
6   2019-09-26T00:00:00  72.0        154       76
7   2019-09-27T00:00:00  71.2        157       58
8   2019-09-28T00:00:00  68.8        140       33
9   2019-09-29T00:00:00  68.9        155       24
10  2019-09-30T00:00:00  71.9        158       64
11  2019-10-01T00:00:00  72.4        162       64
12  2019-10-02T00:00:00  71.9        150       64
13  2019-10-03T00:00:00  70.5        155       46
14  2019-10-04T00:00:00  70.9        148       58
15  2019-10-05T00:00:00  68.3        132       27
16  2019-10-06T00:00:00  67.2        152       26
17  2019-10-07T00:00:00  71.4        166       63
18  2019-10-08T00:00:00  71.3        167       71
19  2019-10-09T00:00:00  72.1        161       72
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. One follow-up: how did you know what the right values were for the `payload` dictionary?

Comment: @sdg Open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab (either in Firefox or Chrome) and reload the page and click on the menu you want to select. You will see there the request with all the parameters the page is doing.